# Your typical sheep counting regular expression in python question

Tags: python, regex

at night, after saying my prayers, i typically count sheep to help me fall asleep.
i want a regular expression to help me with the correct count.
i want the following strings to match

```
0
1sheep
2sheepsheep
3sheepsheepsheep
```

and so on.

what is the regular expression for this?

something like `'(\d+)(sheep){\1}'` if `{\1}` would do what i want it to do

what if i count my sheep in pairs (`1sheepsheep` and `2sheepsheepsheepsheep`), what would the regular expression be then?

Comment: Likely homework.  Please flag with [homework].

Comment: @S.Lott: wrong. I'm looking for a reg exp that matches strings preceded by their length -- standard for many communications protocols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's regular expression engine does not support parsing a matched subexpression to a repetition count, and I don't think this should be done with RegExp either.

The best bet is to combine RegExp matching and checking with code:

```
rx = re.compile(r'^(\d+)((?:sheep)*)$')
m = rx.match(theString)
if m and len(m.group(2)) == 5 * int(m.group(1)):
   print ("Matched")
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not something you should do with regex alone; you should first match the number at the start of the string and then dynamically generate a regex to match the rest. See the other answers for code examples.

I believe this is doable using [Perl regexes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) (search for `(?PARNO)`). This is probably why I don't like Perl.

Comment: The question is on Python, not Perl.

Comment: @KennyTM. I know... I probably shouldn't have posted anything, but I couldn't miss a chance for a dig at Perl. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the digits using a regex, and then compile a second regex using that number on the repetition operator:

```
import re
theString = '2sheepsheep'

rx = re.compile(r'^(\d+)(sheep)*$')
m = rx.match(theString)

rx = re.compile(r'^(\d+)(sheep){' + m.group(1) + '}$')
# If you count in pairs, you can just change that to:
rx = re.compile(r'^(\d+)(sheepsheep){' + m.group(1) + '}$')
```